# Nested aggregation in SQL comes back as null if any parts are null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

forgive me being a newbie to SQL but I'm having a challenging time framing this table data into a more concatenated form where there are NULLs in a couple of the columns. Here's some dummy data from the table:

```
TRIAL_ID    TRT_NO  TRT_NAME    RATE    RATE_UNIT
----------  ------  ----------  ----    ---------
ID19103601  1       Control     NULL    NULL
ID19103601  2       Product201  25      % V/V
ID19103601  3       Product356  16      fl oz/gal
ID19103601  3       Product431  1       fl oz/gal
ID19103601  4       Product008  12.5    % V/V
ID19103601  4       Product123  12.5    % V/V
ID19103601  4       Product745  24      fl oz/gal
ID19500906  1       Control     NULL    NULL
ID19500906  2       Product201  25      % V/V
ID19500906  2       Product356  16      fl oz/gal
ID19500906  3       Product431  1       fl oz/gal
ID19500906  3       Product008  12.5    % V/V
ID19706400  1       Control     NULL    NULL
ID19706400  2       Product745  24      fl oz/gal
ID19706400  2       Product123  12.5    % V/V
ID19706400  2       Product358  16      g/gal
```

So, treatments can have multiple products, meaning I want to display all of the names, followed by their respective rates, in one line for the treatment. I was able to use other examples and get the aggregation to work with the below code. BTW this is SQL Server 2016, so no group_concat or string_agg for me :(

After wrestling for a while on how to define the subquery, this code is what got me to almost my desired result:

```
SELECT t1.TRIAL_ID, t1.TRT_NO,
    (SELECT TRT_NAME + ', (' + CONVERT(varchar(10), RATE) + ' ' + RATE_UNIT + '), '
    FROM dbo.TRT t2
    WHERE t2.TRT_NO = t1.TRT_NO AND t2.TRIAL_ID = t1.TRIAL_ID
    ORDER BY TRT_NO
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ) AS TRT_NAME_CONCAT
FROM dbo.TRT t1
GROUP BY TRIAL_ID, TRT_NO
```

But as you can see, if RATE or RATE_UNIT is NULL, it also deletes the "Control" string. What piece of the puzzle am I missing here?

```
TRIAL_ID    TRT_NO  TRT_NAME_CONCAT
----------  ------  ----------
ID19103601  1   
ID19103601  2       Product201, (25 % V/V),
ID19103601  3       Product356, (16 fl oz/gal), Product431, (1 fl oz/gal),
ID19103601  4       Product008, (12.5 % V/V), Product123, (12.5 % V/V), Product745, (24 fl oz/gal),
ID19500906  1   
ID19500906  2       Product201, (25 % V/V), Product356, (16 fl oz/gal),
ID19500906  3       Product431, (1 fl oz/gal), Product008, (12.5 % V/V),
ID19706400  1   
ID19706400  2       Product745, (24 fl oz/gal), Product123, (12.5 % V/V), Product358, (16 g/gal),
```

I will deal with getting rid of the hanging commas with STUFF later after I know the bones are working properly.
I really am a total noob but I try my best to educate myself up until I'm really stuck. If there's a different/better way to go about this, I'm glad to hear it :)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the `+` operator used for string concatenation.  If any argument is `NULL`, then result is `NULL`.

Instead, use `concat()`.  This may be what you want:

```
(SELECT CONCAT(TRT_NAME, 
               ', (',
               RATE, 
               ' ',
               RATE_UNIT
               '), '
              )
```

This will handle `NULL` values.

The above may have more spaces than you want if one or both rates are `NULL`.  To handle that:

```
(SELECT CONCAT(TRT_NAME, 
               ', (',
               COALESCE(RATE + ' ', ''),
               RATE_UNIT
               '), '
              )
```

This eliminates the extra space if `RATE` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation with a `NULL` value returns a `NULL`. You can check with `ISNULL(@Column, '')` to make your `NULL` value to a space, which will then concatenate correctly.

For example, for your line of code causing the problem:

```
(SELECT TRT_NAME + 
        ', (' + CONVERT(varchar(10), ISNULL(RATE,'')) + 
        ' ' + 
        ISNULL(RATE_UNIT,'') + '), '
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use COALESCE or ISNULL on columns being concatenated so that it won't result to NULL

```
SELECT t1.TRIAL_ID, t1.TRT_NO,
    (SELECT TRT_NAME + ', (' + CONVERT(varchar(10), COALESCE(RATE,'')) + ' ' + COALESCE(RATE_UNIT,'') + '), '
    FROM dbo.TRT t2
    WHERE t2.TRT_NO = t1.TRT_NO AND t2.TRIAL_ID = t1.TRIAL_ID
    ORDER BY TRT_NO
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ) AS TRT_NAME_CONCAT
FROM dbo.TRT t1
GROUP BY TRIAL_ID, TRT_NO
```